# Strong typing deeply nested object structure, avoiding type any

Tags: typescript, types, hash, interface

Our Linting rules doesn't not allow for the quick any solution, so i'm figuring out to Strong Type some nested object structures.

An example:

```
type FlexibleValueType = {
  [key: string]: string | FlexibleValueType
}

export const alphabeticalSortEntries = (a: FlexibleValueType, b: FlexibleValueType) => {
  return a.fields.internal?.default.localeCompare(b.fields.internal?.default)
}
```

Results in:

```
Property 'internal' does not exist on type 'string | FlexibleValueType'.

Property 'internal' does not exist on type 'string'
```

It's either another object for which the property (key) is dynamic, or the value is a string.

How to go about this?

Comment: Check if it isn't a string?

Comment: I assume `FlexValueType` is a typo, right?  Or is it an undeclared type distinct from `FlexibleValueType`?

Comment: You're going to either do runtime checks, or use type assertions, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NlLnQN).  (Why are you writing `internal?.default`?  If it could be `undefined` then you're possibly writing `someString.localCompare(undefined)` which is ill-typed.  You'll need to decide what to do in this case explicitly; I'm just going to ignore it here.)  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz copy/paste typo yes. Changed FlexValueType to FlexibleValueType for more descriptiveness while I was writing. Fixed it #edit

Comment: There’s still a typo in the code.  Also, could you address my second comment?  There’s a link to a demonstration of the approaches you can take.

Comment: @jcalz Fixed other type as well (sloppy..). Your example makes sense, will look into that asap, will let you know

Comment: @jcalz both approaches in your 2nd comment make sense and make it possible for me to move forward, solving my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an inherent tradeoff to making types "flexible" (usually we'd say *wide* or *general*) versus making them "rigid" (or *narrow* or *specific*). It is easier to *supply* a value of a flexible type because you have more options, but it is harder to *consume* such a value because you have less information about it.  Conversely it is easier to *consume* a value of a rigid type because you know more about what it is, but it is harder to *supply* such a value because you have less flexibility.

Compare the types

```
type FlexibleValueType = {
  [key: string]: string | FlexibleValueType
}
```

with

```
type RigidValueType = {
  fields: {
    internal: {
      default: string;
    }
  }
}
```

from the point of view of your `alphabeticalSortEntries` function, the *consumer* of the type.  If you had `RigidValueType` parameters, it would be easy to implement that function:

```
const alphabeticalSortEntriesRigid = (a: RigidValueType, b: RigidValueType) =>
  a.fields.internal.default.localeCompare(b.fields.internal.default);
```

But you apparently need to consume `FlexibleValueType` arguments instead.  And there's no guarantee that a `FlexibleValueType` will be a `RigidValueType`, so if you just write the same implementation, the compiler will warn you that what you're doing isn't safe.  After all, `a` or `b` might be `{oops: "lol"}`, a perfectly valid `FlexibleValueType` but not a `RigidValueType`, and your implementation would explode as soon as you try to dereference the undefined `a.fields`.

---

So how should you proceed?  Ideally you'd just use `RigidValueType` instead of `FlexibleValueType`.  But if you can't, then you either need to do enough checking to convince the compiler that `a` and `b` have the right structure, or you have to just tell the compiler to *assume* that they do (and face any runtime consequences if the assumption is wrong).

Checking is tedious but relatively safe:

```
function getFieldsInternalDefault(a: FlexibleValueType): string {
  const aFields = a.fields;
  if (typeof aFields !== "object") throw new Error();
  const aFieldsInternal = aFields.internal;
  if (typeof aFieldsInternal === "string") throw new Error();
  const aFieldsInternalDefault = aFieldsInternal?.default;
  if (typeof aFieldsInternalDefault !== "string") throw new Error();
  return aFieldsInternalDefault;
}

export const alphabeticalSortEntries =
  (a: FlexibleValueType, b: FlexibleValueType) =>
    getFieldsInternalDefault(a).localeCompare(getFieldsInternalDefault(b))
```

while [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the values are the right type is simple but relatively unsafe:

```
export const alphabeticalSortEntries = (a: FlexibleValueType, b: FlexibleValueType) =>
  alphabeticalSortEntriesRigid(a as RigidValueType, b as RigidValueType)
```

It's up to you and your use cases to determine what you want to do here.

[Playground ink to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNhAHgSwEYIGoEM4FcIAq40AvFAN4CwAUFFANoDWEIAXFAM7ABOyAdgHMAuuy69BUAD6wEKdBGx5CxGgF8aNAGa4+AY2DIA9nygCIwGMghwAJhwCSfYBG58cAEQiasuOMAAUWOzwSGiYOPhEkACUojz8AhQ0dLrGXFBYltZ2UGRYAHSaVrYcANzJUMiaUP6gkIbVmcU5AIQkZABEhqgAVhD6HdFQwAAW3IYA7lB8EFMAotzj3P7R5bRQqXzpTdkOTi5ucLkZWSX5-M6uOGt0VTV1EA0nzXuXh7ntUB1iCYPDY5NprMoAslisbhs0sBnrtHG8PF4fH5jjsSnCDjgAPz5GyI3zACF3WrEJ6ouzoq5wTzefFQNqdH6CP6jcZTGbzRaGZarCrccy4VwwtH7SnUpEEtQaahIMBc6GbbZwMAjLCoczIXQ4ADKcrmTl4EA4uQqgWCsjCCgiykgABooKgzaF5IpIsQhiQAHwVOhmCwvCmHMX4wLRfJwQyahAAYUMAFswFg+f5fadySLA3i-P5UNFolL89QHlAAErIATIGwu62kJLrIq7dhUda3dM4RveuhQXE0vxxcQCCF0dTrYfDmgAenHUFwHGgRawHFn3AMaRoMrlkK20JwytV6sjOuXevihoATMdTTIneElFEIHaHVe5DfXTFcl71juVWqDAfdfqrA4UtyxsQIMiNYCKyrO8H3Aksyygq07zzagaAVbclW-fdtX-E8gIQmwLyCeCQOg4gH3YSDKyQt13wqAp6zOC4MTgHFM2AMMIxwCAY3jRMIGzQoXnOVtWO7cVViAA)